# Jupyter notebook cannot pick up the latest python version installed on Google VM

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I cannot upgrade the version of the Python Notebook on Google Cloud from 3.5 to 3.6. I have installed Python 3.6.

On terminal, it shows me the python3 version has been updated to 3.6.

```
jupyter@intel-20190810-94122:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.3
```

But on Jupyter Notebook, the version is still 3.5.

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
3.5.3
```

Comment: Can you reinstall Ipython? If I remember correctly, the IPython kernel is the Python execution backend for Jupyter. So if you installed Ipython when you had python 3.5,  then your notebooks are going to be using the older version no mater what you do. Reinstalling Ipython now that you have python 3.6 should fix that :)

Comment: Are you launching Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda or something similar?

Comment: It's the Jupyter notebook on the Google Platform.

Comment: how did you solve this issue? I have the same issue now